# Как выбрать файл для загрузки и сохранить его?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

Веб приложение на Flutter использует библиотеку ResumableJS для загрузки файлов на сервер. Да, это не самое простое решение, но так нужно.
При выборе файла (как правило - изображения) необходимо показать его в интерфейсе приложения перед отправкой. Однако я не могу получить сам файл картинки в коде Flutter, не понимаю, как его вытащить из методов библиотеки и сконвертировать в файл любого пригодного формата.
Вот код в моем index.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/resumablejs@1.1.0/resumable.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var apiUrl = "https://**********/api/";
  var progressBar = 0;
  var photoDescriptionUrl1 = "";
  var photoDescriptionUrl2 = "";
  var photoDescriptionUrl3 = "";
  var photoDescriptionUrl4 = "";
  var photoDescriptionUrl5 = "";
  var photoDescriptionUrl6 = "";
  var productPromoPictureURL = "";
  var productMiniPromoPictureURL = "";
  var productLogoURL = "";
  var nowUploading = [];

  //****** event for uploading **************
  document.addEventListener("uploadFile", function (event) {
    console.log("upload file ---- ", event.detail);
    initResumable(
      event.detail.fieldName,
      event.detail.userId,
      event.detail.fileType
    );
  });

  function initResumable(fieldName, userId, fileType) {
    var uploader = new Resumable({
      target: `${apiUrl}product/upload/${userId}`,
      chunkSize: 0.5 * 1024 * 1024,
      testChunks: false,
      prioritizeFirstAndLastChunk: true,
      maxFiles: 1,
    });
    uploader.opts.fileType = fileType;
    uploader.assignBrowse(document.getElementById(fieldName));

    uploader.on("fileAdded", (file, event) => {
      nowUploading.push(file.uniqueIdentifier);

      console.log("upload now...");
      uploader.upload();

      var event = new CustomEvent("uploadedFile", {
        detail: {
          file: file.file,
        },
      });
      console.log("file---", file);
      document.dispatchEvent(event);
    });

    uploader.on("fileSuccess", (file, message) => {
      console.log("uploaded ok", file, "for", fieldName);
      if (fieldName === "photoDescriptionUrl1R") {
        photoDescriptionUrl1 = file.fileName;
      } else if (fieldName === "photoDescriptionUrl2R") {
        photoDescriptionUrl2 = file.fileName;
      } else if (fieldName === "photoDescriptionUrl3R") {
        photoDescriptionUrl3 = file.fileName;
      } else if (fieldName === "photoDescriptionUrl4R") {
        photoDescriptionUrl4 = file.fileName;
      } else if (fieldName === "photoDescriptionUrl5R") {
        photoDescriptionUrl5 = file.fileName;
      } else if (fieldName === "photoDescriptionUrl6R") {
        photoDescriptionUrl6 = file.fileName;
      } else if (fieldName === "productLogoURL") {
        productLogoURL = file.fileName;
      } else if (fieldName === "productLauncherFileUrl") {
      } else if (fieldName === "productPromoPictureURL") {
        productPromoPictureURL = file.fileName;
      } else if (fieldName === "productLauncherFileUrl") {
      } else if (fieldName === "productMiniPromoPictureURL") {
        productMiniPromoPictureURL = file.fileName;
      } else if (fieldName === "productLauncherFileUrl") {
        this.form.productLauncher.get(fieldName).setValue(file.fileName);
      } else {
        this.form.setValue(file.fileName);
      }
      console.log("file URL is", file.fileName);
      return file.fileName;
    });
    uploader.on("pause", (file, message) => {
      console.log("pause", file, message);
    });
    uploader.on("fileProgress", (file, message) => {
      progressBar = uploader.progress();
      console.log("fileProgress", this.progressBar);
    });
    uploader.on("fileError", (file, message) => {
      console.log("fileError", file, message);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Хочу обратить внимание, что сама загрузка файлов работает хорошо, без проблем и сбоев.
Вот как я работаю с библиотекой в dart коде, чтобы получить событие fileAdded:

```
html.document.on["uploadedFile"].listen((html.Event event) {
  var res = (event as html.CustomEvent).detail;
  var res1 = Map.from(res);
  var reet = res1.values.first;

  final reader = html.FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(reet);
  setState(() {
    image = Image.memory(reet);
  });

  print(res1.toString());
});
```

Моя проблема в том, что не получается вытащить файл из ответа и сконвертировать его для нужного виджету формата. Выдает ошибку

```
Uncaught Error: Expected a value of type 'Uint8List', but got one of type 'File$
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать?

Comment: Могу предположить что не правильно используете FileReader,
Пример можно посмотреть тут https://opoloo.github.io/jquery_upload_preview/assets/js/jquery.uploadPreview.js

Comment: Вы правы! Я не понимал его работу, теперь разобрался, все исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот мое решение, я действительно неправильно использовал FileReader:

```
uploadImage() {
    html.document.on["uploadedFile"].listen((html.Event event) async {
      var details = (event as html.CustomEvent).detail;
      var result = Map.from(details);
      print(result);

      html.File file = result['file'];
      String _field = result['fieldName'];

      if (_field == widget.fieldName) {
        final reader = new html.FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        await reader.onLoadEnd.first;

        var _imageRes = reader.result;
        setState(() {
          image = Image.memory(_imageRes);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Image.memory();` принимает `Uint8List` (байты), а вы передаете `File` (Ссылка на файл в файловой системе). По идее вам должен подойти `Image.file();`, но я не уверен в полученном `File`...

Comment: да, файл получал не от dart:io а dart:html
Я решил проблему, надо свой ответ опубликовать